# AS CODE: FIVE BIT ⇐ U SAW/SEE

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

```
AS CODE: FIVE BIT ⇐ U SAW/SEE
```

[image: Twenty side-by-side 2x3 grids. The middle row is highlighted green.]

As always, your final answer will be a single word.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As hinted by the given grid,

> we should convert the given text (letters only) to Braille. This gives "⠁⠎⠉⠕⠙⠑⠋⠊⠧⠑⠃⠊⠞⠥⠎⠁⠺⠎⠑⠑".

Then,

> reading the middle row of dots as five-bit binary (00001 = A, 00010 = B, ...) spells out the answer: **DEMIURGE**.